# What if i charge a battery with low ampere.?

Tags: batteries, charger

Assuming we have a mobile-phone LiIon battery and a charger which is only able to supply less ampere than the original one, will it damage the battery if i charge with less ampere charger than the original one.

e.g charging a battery with a universal charger rather than it's original charger

Comment: Please post more details.  In its present form, your question is unclear.

Comment: You mean: *Can I charge a battery with an adapter having a lower current rating than the original adapter ? Will it damage the battery ?* Answer: Yes you can **but** it is not the battery which is at danger. You can always charge a battery with less current. Heck you can even **not charge** it (no current). But if the battery wants to charge with more current than the adapter can handle, the **adapter might overload**. If it's a good adapter it will just switch off. If it's a crappy one **it might catch fire**. So your choice.

Comment: "Heck you can even not charge it (no current)" nicely put :) 
If you are talking about the battery for mobile phones (Lion), it will not draw more than it gets. So you're save. The only question is why would you want that? I suggest getting a better charger, not worse. people usually try to charge with more current, not less.. Just for the record, max current is 1C (e.g. if your battery has 2800mAh, 2.8A is max). 
Read more [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_lithium_ion_batteries) and [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Li-ion-battery-charging/)

Comment: It takes longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the term charger to mean the external power supply used to provide charging energy.
The actual charger is almost always an electronic unit within the phone, with the external unit being better described as a power supply.

If the battery is a Lithium Ion or Lithium Polymer battery, both of which are essentially the same electrically, then a charger of the correct voltage but lower rated current:

- Will take longer to charge.

If the charger is capable of X% of the charge current of the original one then  it will take approximately 100/X times longer.

eg if a 6A charger is specified and you use a 4A charger it will take ABOUT 6/4 = 1.5 times longer.

- May damage the charger but in many cases will do no damage.
- Sometimes, but not usually, may not charge at all if the charger maximum current is below some loose limit set by the phone.